# Wordpress 3.9.1 installed from YUM in CentOS does not allow install plugins or themes

Tags: centos, wordpress

I installed Wordpress 3.9.1 using YUM in a CentOS, however it does not allow me to install any plugins or themes (the install buttons do not appear).

I tried many things:

1. Changed the file permissions of /usr/share/wordpress and /etc/wordpress to be writable by apache:

> sudo chown -R apache:apache wordpress

2. Commented lines in wp-config.php

> /* define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true); */
>   /*define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true); */

But it does not seem to work.

Any idea what do I need to modify>

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs ? There is a [wordpress.se] too.

Comment: Nop. Nothing in the error logs

Comment: How do you mean, you installed wordpress with yum? What repository did you get it from?

Comment: Basically I did: "sudo yum install wordpress.noarch" . No idea where it got it from...